# VSCode not suggesting and autocompleting java code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I was making a java program in VSCode and I noticed that suggestion, error reporting and autocomplete features are not working. A notification showing below error popped up:

```
Sorry, something went wrong activating IntelliCode support for Java. Please check the "Language 
Support for Java" and "VS IntelliCode" output windows for details.
```

I tried finding the error in settings but couldn't find any. Also I tried first uninstalling and then reinstalling the above mentioned extension,  but it didn't help.

Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: Could you get any helpful information in the 'Language Support for Java' and 'VS IntelliCode' output panel? And could you downgrade 'Language support for Java' extension to make a try? Have you upgraded the jdk version to jdk11? As the jdk11 was the minimum requirement of 'Language support for Java' for now.

Comment: No. i haven't don any of that. But do I really need to upgrade to JDK 11

Comment: I also couldn't locate output panel which you are talking about.

Comment: select the output panel which close to the terminal panel, then choose the 'Language Support for Java' and 'VS IntelliCode' channel.

Answer (score 17):

### This problem might occur if you're using an older version of Java (below 11).

To fix this:

> 1. Open VScode and go to Preferences -> Settings
> 2. Search **java.configuration.runtimes**
> 3. Select **Edit in settings.json** and paste the follwing:

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-8",
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-11",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-11",
    "default": true
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-14",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-14",
  },
]
```

> 4. Specify the path of the JDK which you would like to use in **"path:"**
>
> > usually the path of JDK for macOS is
> > `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

> 5. Set **"default": true** for that JDK

Suppose if you would like to use JDK 11, set **"default": true** in that code block.

Check for additional information
[here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements#java.configuration.runtimes).

Comment: This should be the right solution. Thanks!

Comment: But it throws some red line errors in libraries like Selenium functions. How do we avoid that?

Comment: Not works, the problem still persists.

Comment: it doent work. THis is the solution given everywhere in the forums. But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 8):

### Update on July 12, 2022

The Language Support for Java extension now contained a Java runtime by itself, which is used to launch the extension. That means in most cases, you don't need to specify `java.home` and `jdt.ls.java.home`.

All you need to do is use the setting `java.configuration.runtimes` to specify all the JDKs you have installed on your machine. Then the extension will pick the most suitable JDK according to your project's configuration.

---

There are two kinds of JDKs that VS Code Java will use.

**I guess your problem is caused by that the Language Server cannot find a valid JDK to launch itself. (See the next paragraph about how to fix it)**

- The first kind is the JDK that is used to launch the Java Language Server, which requires JDK 11 or higher. And the setting `java.home` is used to specify which JDK is used to launch the Language Server. Make sure you set this setting and the Java version is >= 11.
- The second kind is the JDKs that is used to build/launch your project. That's controlled by the setting `java.configuration.runtimes`, which is also mentioned by @Jayan Praveen's answer.

Comment: The problem is solved. It was occuring because I was using older version of java.

Comment: That was it for me. I had set java.configuration.runtimes but not java.home. It was set in my global settings (to the Windows jdk) but not in the workspace settings which was WSL. I set java.home in the workspace settings.json (to the path valid in the WSL Debian instance) and it worked.

Comment: doesnt work. The java code still throws errors.