# VSCode Java Automcomplete Issues

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have already tried doing what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468403/vscode-not-suggesting-and-autocompleting-java-code) says (the solution completely sounded unrelated anyway), asked Bing for a lot of help on the issue, changed a lot of things in `settings.json`, re-installed all Java extensions *after* deleting them from `~/.vscode/extensions`, but I still can't figure out what went wrong.

Settings I tried adding:

```json
"java.project.sourcePaths": [
        "src"
    ],
"java.completion.enabled": true,
"java.configuration.runtimes": [ // This one comes from the post I mentioned.
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "/home/brahvim/java/jdk-17.0.7+7/",
            "default": true
        }
    ],
"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/home/brahvim/java/jdk-17.0.7+7",
// ^^^ Still have this from the older days for some reason - didn't *add* it in explicitly.
```

The issue? VSCode does not automatically type out the body of a method that's overriden, when given method signatures. *For example,*

```java
class A {
  protected void draw() {
  }
}

// ...In some other file:

class B extends A {
  draw // <-- Upon pressing `Tab`, VSCode should automatically fill:

  /*
   * @Override
   * protected void draw() {
   * }
   */

  // ...But I see nothing of value in the autocompletions list.
  // The only suggestion says "double" - must've gotten fuzzy matched with "draw".

}
```

PS The class I extended **is** from the source code in my workspace.

I've also started a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3186).

*Thank you very much for any comments or help you may offer!*

Comment: Possibly related:  https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191