# My VScode intellisense not working in my java project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

For example When am create the new test.java file the intellisense only show up only 1 or 2 statement that I don't want really to use it. the temporary way to fix it I have to restart the Vscode then the test.java file will show all the suggest statement but if I create new file it will have the same problem. So is it have the way to fix it permanent. thankyou.

## fixing my Vscode problem

Comment: quite possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76641794/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/76631184/11107541. possibly even https://stackoverflow.com/q/76594445/11107541

Comment: Had the same problem, I opened a [report](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191) that you can follow.

Comment: oh thx. I hope we will found the solution soon.

Answer (score -2):

BTW, today the Vscode have an update just update and it's fixing thx everyone

Comment: please don't answer duplicate questions. see [answer].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).