# Intellisense only works if i create a new project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

If I create a new file in existing project then it stops working
[image: If i create another file then it stops working]

On the other hand if I create a new project then it works
[image: On the other hand if i create a new project then it works]

I have checked out the Java redhat setting also but still have found no clue. I tried reinstalling the extension pack for java but still it has the same problem.

Comment: it'd be hard to suggest anything given there are many things that can affect the plugin, at least but not limited to: 1) java version; 2) plugin version; 3) are the sdk properly configured

Comment: is there any video where i can get help to check such stuff

Comment: [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468403/vscode-not-suggesting-and-autocompleting-java-code) you could try out

Comment: what if you trigger suggestions manually? ctrl/cmd+space

Comment: when i trigger it manually it only shows a few like psvm,main,switch and not the other like sout,system,in etc.

Comment: it only works when i do clean java server workspace

Comment: please [edit] your question post to give us a longer list (at least 10 items if there are that many, but the more you give, the more helpful it is) of what you see in the suggestion list, and what you don't see but you expect to see.

Comment: It may not be that the new project takes effect, but restarting vscode takes effect. You can restart vscode in an existing project and see if intellisense works.

Comment: the specific problem here with typing `Sys` to get the `sysout` snippet may be related to this change: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/pull/3142, but it's weird that you get _different_ behaviour upon restart...

Comment: @JialeDu yes it only works if i restart vscode or create a new project or restart the server workspace. If i create a new file in the existing part it stops working

Comment: Follow here:  https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3191#issuecomment-1635181642

> this issue has been fixed in the latest vscode@1.80.1 version.